# "unknown type name" error in C with Typedef in .h file

Tags: c, struct, header-files

I am attempting to create a linked list in C using node structs, but I am having an error with my functions getting an "unknown type error".

```
    #ifndef Node_h
    #define Node_h

    #include <stdio.h>
    /* Add employee struct and Node struct */

    typedef struct Employee {
        char *firstName;
        char *lastName;
    }employee_t;

    typedef struct Node{
        struct employee_t *empInfo;
        struct node_t *next;
    }node_t;
    /*
     Prints all employee names in the following format
     LastName, firstName
    */
    void print_list (node_t * head);

    /*
    Adds a new node to the end of the list
    */
    void addToEnd(node_t **head, employee_t *employee);  

    /*
    ...
```

I have defined my structs and all my functions in this Node.h file. Below in my node.c file where my functions are is where the errors are occurring.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    /* Add employee struct and Node struct */

    /*
     Prints all employee names in the following format
     LastName, firstName
    */

    void print_list (node_t * head){ //here is where the error occurs
        node_t *current_node;
        current_node = head;
        while(current_node != NULL){
            printf("%s", current_node->empInfo);
            current_node = current_node->next;
        }
    }
    /*
     Adds a new node to the end of the list
     */
     void addToEnd(node_t **head, employee_t *employee){ //here is where the error occurs
        node_t *current_node;
        node_t *new_node;
        current_node = *head;
        while(current_node->next != NULL){
            current_node = current_node->next;
        }
        new_node = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current_node->next = new_node;
        new_node->empInfo = employee;
        new_node->next = NULL;
    } 

    ...
```

in my function declarations in node.c I am getting the error "unknown error type 'node_t', did you mean..." or "unknown error type "unknown error type 'employee_t', did you mean..."

here is my main for extra context:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include "node.h"

     int main (void) {

        setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
        setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

         employee_t *empPtr1, emp1,*empPtr2, emp2,*empPtr3, emp3,*empPtr4, emp4,*empPtr5, 
         emp5,*empPtr6, emp6, *empPtr7, emp7, *empPtr8, emp8, *empPtr9, emp9;
         empPtr1 = &emp1;
         empPtr2 = &emp2;
         empPtr3 = &emp3;
         empPtr4 = &emp4;
         empPtr5 = &emp5;
         empPtr6 = &emp6;
         empPtr7 = &emp7;
         empPtr8 = &emp8;
         empPtr9 = &emp9;
         node_t head;
         node_t *headPtr;
         node_t **headPtr2;
         headPtr2 = &headPtr;
         headPtr = &head;

             printf("Please enter the first name of the first employee you'd like to add:");
             scanf("%s", empPtr1->firstName);
             printf("Please enter the last name of the first employee you'd like to add:");
             scanf("%s", empPtr1->lastName);

         addToEnd(headPtr2, empPtr1);
    ...
```

I would appreciate any help I cant get, thank you!

Comment: You need `#include <node.h>` in the Node.c

Answer (score 3):

You first need to include your header file in your 'node.c' source file:
`#include "node.h"`

You are also mixing up your typedef and struct namespaces within your header file:

```
typedef struct Employee {
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
}employee_t;

typedef struct Node{
    struct employee_t *empInfo; // this should be either 'employee_t *' or 'struct Employee *'
    struct node_t *next; // This should be 'struct Node *'
}node_t;
```